# Php - getting the distance between multiple points using lon, lat and alt

Tags: php, xml, coordinates, distance

So i want to load a gpx file and get all the cordinates and calculate the total distance traveled, but im stuck with this code:

```
    <?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("data/example.gpx");

    echo $xml->metadata->author->name;
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";

    echo "</br>";

    $lon1=0;
    $lat1=0;
    $lon2=0;
    $lat2=0;
    $alt1=0;
    $alt2=0;
    $dist=0;

    $brr = count($xml->trk->trkseg);
    $brf = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i<$brr; $i++){

    $br = count($xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt);
    $brf= $brf + $br;

    for($j = 0; $j<$br;$j++){

    $lat2= (float) $xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt[$j]['lat'];
    $lon2= (float) $xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt[$j]['lon'];
    $alt2= (float) $xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt[$j]->ele;

    $lon2 = $alt2 * cos($lat2) * sin($lon2);
    $lat2 = $alt2 * sin($lat2);
    $alt2 = $alt2 * cos($lat2) * cos($lon2);

    if ($j==0){    //this is just for the first time because first points are not set
        $lat1=$lat2;
        $lon1=$lon2;
        $alt1=  $alt2;
        }

    $cdist = sqrt(pow(($lat2-$lat1),2) + pow(($lon2-$lon1),2) + pow(($alt2-$alt1),2));
    $dist = $dist + $cdist;

    $lat1=$lat2;
    $lon1=$lon2;
    $alt1=$alt2;
    }
    }

    echo 'Distance = '.$dist;
    echo '</br>';
    echo 'number of coordinates = '.$brf;
    ?>
```

as result for distance i get the number  4592.6244157763 instead of 4.10km (~~4100), but coordinates are good, it goes through all coordinates. (also, the gpx file is from endomondo if it matters)

Comment: is this a mathematical problem or or programming issue?

Comment: The big mistery is how you can get 4592 when both lat1/lon1 and lat2/lon2 is 0.

Comment: @Andreas first line in `for` loop.

Comment: @Jeff Ahh.. I see we are supposed to guess what lat/lon he uses.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Fixed the code, in case anyone needs it, here it is:</strike>

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("data/vladantd.gpx");

echo $xml->metadata->author->name;
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";



echo "</br>";

$lon1=0;
$lat1=0;
$lon2=0;
$lat2=0;
$alt1=0;
$alt2=0;
$dist=0;


$brr = count($xml->trk->trkseg);
$brf = 0;

for($i = 0; $i<$brr; $i++){

$br = count($xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt);
$brf= $brf + $br;

for($j = 0; $j<$br;$j++){
    if($j==0)
    {
        $j=1;
        $g=1;

    }
$lat2= (float) $xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt[$j]['lat'];
$lon2= (float) $xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt[$j]['lon'];
$alt2= (float) $xml->trk->trkseg[$i]->trkpt[$j]->ele;

$lon2 = $alt2 * cos($lat2) * sin($lon2);
$lat2 = $alt2 * sin($lat2);
$alt2 = $alt2 * cos($lat2) * cos($lon2);

if ($g==1){
    $lat1=$lat2;
    $lon1=$lon2;
    $alt1=  $alt2;
    $j=0;
    $g=0;
    }

$cdist = sqrt(pow(($lat2-$lat1),2) + pow(($lon2-$lon1),2) + pow(($alt2-$alt1),2));
$dist = $dist + $cdist;

$lat1=$lat2;
$lon1=$lon2;
$alt1=$alt2;
}
}

echo 'Distance = '.$dist;
echo '</br>';
echo 'number of coordinates = '.$brf;
?>
```

<strike>okay, so the files that i use, every first trkpt in every trkseg doesnt have an altitude, so if j==0 then set j to 1, so it skips that first point (it sets points 1 time every few seconds so it shouldnt make a big difference (in my case) and at the same time i've set another variable g to 1, so that we can at the end of this current loop, return j back to 0 so the j++ increases it to 1 instead of skipping the point and increasing it to 2, rest should be clear, if you have any questions, just ask ^^</strike>

EDIT:

The code isnt working good. The longer the distance, the bigger the mistake it makes, for 8.1km it shows 9km, tested it out on a few gpx files and noticed. Sorry, if someone has a solution, would mean a lot!

Comment: maybe add an explanation what you've changed?

Comment: That is only 10% off. What is it you mean is the correct number? I understand you use some sort of Gps to get the gpx file and from there you get 9 km. But what tells you it's 8.1 km?

Comment: @Andreas the gps tells me that the distance was 8.1km, my code says 9km, and the bigger the real distance, more bigger the mistake that my code makes is, at 8km its ~9%, then it starts changimg as the distance grows, example, instead of 8.6km, it will show 10.2km

Comment: and what happens if you compare to a "rough" google maps with the ruler. Or perhaps another online service for example: http://utrack.crempa.net/ I just want to be sure the GPS is correct and the code wrong.

Comment: @Andreas im sorry for not replying, i kinda gave up on it, but before i gave up, i removed the third point (elevation) and without it i get somewhat close to the real location. i didnt post it because as the title says, using lon, lat and Altitude, and since i gave up on altitude, i just didnt think anyone cared. i changed the formula totally, and now endomondo says 10.13km and my code gives me 9.92km, but i can asure you, that the old code didnt have the correct formula, because the bigger the real distance is, the bigger mistake my code made, for 8km it made a +1km, for 9km it did + ~~2km